# Evaluate formulas in xlsb worksheet via python?

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, openpyxl, xlsb

I have an .xlsb file that contains 5 sheets: Sheet A, Sheet B, Sheet C, Sheet D, Sheet E

Sheet A, Sheet B, Sheet C and Sheet D - Contains data in every cell

Sheet E: Contains formulas in every cell

Note: The formulas that sheet E contains refers to values from Sheet A, Sheet B, Sheet C and Sheet D. Those formulas also have circular references for some cells.

What I want to do is: Update values in a few cells across Sheet A, Sheet B, Sheet C and Sheet D and Sheet E should calculate the new value based on the formulas using the updated values of the other 4 sheets.

Is there a standard way people use to perform the task I want to?

Language desired: Python

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43850711/how-to-update-equation-links-using-openpyxl xlwings is your friend in runtime formula calculation.